# Trouble with jQuery Cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm am new to creating cookies and need to create one for a jquery popup.

Cookie_name = newsletter_displayed - value should be a date, expiration 1 month - If newsletter_displayed is set don't show until 4 minutes has passed.

I have the time set to 3 and 5 seconds for testing purposes. When I click on the x, the cookies are set and it works. However when I refresh the page the popup occurs again. How do I make it where the popup hides for the existence of the cookie?

My HTML:

```
<div id="slide">    
    <div id="dialog">
        <div id="close">x</div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p class="text-center">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER TO RECEIVE EXCLUSIVE DISCOUNTS AND INDUSTRY NEWS.</p>
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter-email" class="required-entry validate-email input-text form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address..."> 
            </div> 
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="submit-btn form-control text-center" type="submit">Subscribe <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#slide").delay(3000).animate({width:'toggle'}, 750);
    });
jQuery('#close').on('click', function() {

        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var slide = jQuery('#slide');
        if ($this.hasClass('clicked-once')) {
        // already been clicked once, hide it
        createCookie('newsletter_suppressed', 'new Date()', 30);
        if(createCookie('newsletter_displayed', 'new Date()', 30) == 'undefined') {
        createCookie('newsletter_displayed', 'new Date()', 30);
        } else {
        slide.hide();
        }
    } else {
        // first time this is clicked, mark it
        createCookie('newsletter_displayed', 'new Date()', 30);
        $this.addClass('clicked-once');
        jQuery(slide).fadeOut();
        jQuery(slide).delay(5000).animate({width:'toggle'}, 750);
    }    

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if(!readCookie('newsletter_suppressed')) {
    jQuery("#slide").delay(3000).animate({width:'toggle'}, 750);
}
jQuery('#close').on('click', function() {

    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var slide = jQuery('#slide');

    if ($this.hasClass('clicked-once')) {
        // already been clicked once, hide it
        createCookie('newsletter_suppressed', new Date(), 30);
        slide.hide();

    } else {
        // first time this is clicked, mark it
        createCookie('newsletter_displayed', new Date(), 30);
        $this.addClass('clicked-once');
        jQuery(slide).fadeOut();
        jQuery(slide).delay(5000).animate({width:'toggle'}, 750);
    }    
});
```

});